# request.get returning traceback error, looking for better way to pull data from url

Tags: python, api

I was someone could take a look at my code and see if I am making an  obvious mistake. I have a URL and an API key that I would like to use to pull data from but I am not sure the best way to do it. Below is what I have tried so far.

```
import requests


url = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/madmrmeeseeks'
headers = 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX'

r = 
requests.get('https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/madmrmeeseeks', 
headers = 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX')

print(r.text)
```

I am populating 'TRN-Api-Key' with my API key.

Unfortunately this is returning many errors (Traceback (most recent call last). I am too new to this to work through them all but was hoping someone might be able to point out something obvious in the code or point me in the right direction if there is a better way to pull data from the URL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly defining your headers, it must be a `dict`. Try this:

```
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/madmrmeeseeks', headers = {'TRN-Api-Key': 'XXXXXXX'})

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Those little things are going to be the toughest part as I work through learning this stuff. That did the trick. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to help! Please consider marking the answer as correct so it can be of help to others as well.